# Create a android sqlite contain a table with only single row

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to create a android sqlite table with only one single row, for insert or update and read, how can i do that, cause i only know how to create mulitiple row

the table contain only 1 single row , is for user insert data and store , when read the data will come out , and last the update mean it will override the data which in that row.

this is my DBHelperNote.java

```
 public static final String TABLE_GOAL = "goal";
    public static final String GOAL_ID= "goal_id";
    public static final String GENDER = "gender";
    public static final String AGE = "age";
    public static final String HEIGHT = "height";
    public static final String WEIGHT = "weight";
    public static final String GOAL = "goal";

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_GOAL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_GOAL + " (" +
                    GOAL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    GENDER + " text not null, " +
                    AGE + " text not null, "+
                    HEIGHT + " text not null, "+
                    WEIGHT + " text not null, "+
                    GOAL + " text not null "+
                    " );";
```

this is  SQLControlerWeight.java

```
public void insertGoal(String gd,String age,String hg,String wg,,String gl) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBHelperNote.GENDER, gd);
        cv.put(DBHelperNote.AGE, age);
        cv.put(DBHelperNote.HEIGHT, hg);
        cv.put(DBHelperNote.WEIGHT, wg);
        cv.put(DBHelperNote.GOAL, gl);
        database.insert(DBHelperNote.TABLE_GOAL, null, cv);
    }

    public Cursor readGoal() {
        String[] allColummn = new String[] {
                DBHelperNote.GOAL_ID,
                DBHelperNote.GENDER,
                DBHelperNote.AGE,
                DBHelperNote.HEIGHT,
                DBHelperNote.WEIGHT,
                DBHelperNote.GOAL,
        };
        Cursor c = database.query(DBHelperNote.TABLE_GOAL, allColummn, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

this actually is the method to read data put but it is from array mean multiple row , but i don't Know how to change it to only call one row

```
dbconnection = new SQLControlerWeight(this);
        dbconnection.openDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = dbconnection.readGoal();

        String[] from = new String[]{
                DBHelperNote.GOAL_ID,
                DBHelperNote.GENDER,
                DBHelperNote.AGE,
                DBHelperNote.HEIGHT,
                DBHelperNote.WEIGHT,
                DBHelperNote.GOAL,
        };
        int[] to = new int[]{
                R.id.goal_id,
                R.id.field_gender,
                R.id.field_age,
                R.id.field_height,
                R.id.field_weight,
                R.id.field_goal,

        };
```

Comment: update your table with same `GOAL_ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will be having GOAL_ID ones inserted you can modify you insert function as

```
public void insertGoal(String goal_id, String gd,String age,String hg,String wg,,String gl) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if (goal_id != null){
            cv.put(DBHelperNote.GOAL_ID, goal_id);
        }
        cv.put(DBHelperNote.GENDER, gd);
        cv.put(DBHelperNote.AGE, age);
        cv.put(DBHelperNote.HEIGHT, hg);
        cv.put(DBHelperNote.WEIGHT, wg);
        cv.put(DBHelperNote.GOAL, gl);
        database.replace(DBHelperNote.TABLE_GOAL, null, cv);
    }
```

Modification done is changed insert to replace, which will make sure if primary key value is provided and row exists with that id then it will replace the existing row without creating new one. Most important is the if condition for checking whether goal_id is null or not, if null then don't provide that in contentvalue.

Modify the if condition properly for proper comparison for Goal_id as i have just used the one i can visualize from your question content.

Comment: but how about the readGoal() , cause mine readGoal method actually is read array , but now i have only 1 row , so i can change my code?

Comment: that won't make difference as it will read all the rows available in cursor, so if one then will read one, if n rows then will read n rows

Comment: i getting this row error cv.put(DBHelperNote.GOAL_ID, <goal_id>); ? 
this <goal_id> is ? "goal_id" is ?

Comment: it is the value of the id. i used <goal_id> so that you can substitute with the variable containing goal_id value.

Comment: same error cv.put(DBHelperNote.GOAL_ID,<goal_id>);  , the <goal_id> can resolve the symbol ?

Comment: I didn't know you won't be able to figure out this simple thing. You require to add one more parameter your insert named String goal_id, and check this if goal_id is null or not, if not null then pass the cv.put(DBHelperNote.GOAL_ID, goal_id); else don't. passing goal_id is like passing other variables to function "String gd,String age,String hg,String wg,,String gl"

Comment: i aldy update my post, gv you more detail to look on

Comment: you mean i add String goal_id in here {String gd,String age,String hg,String wg,,String gl} like { String goal_id,String gd,String age,String hg,String wg,,String gl} and change my code to cv.put(DBHelperNote.GOAL_ID, goal_id); ?

Answer (score 0):

Use RawQuery method its little bit easier.

c1 = db.rawQuery("select * from Table_Name", null);
c1.moveToFirst();

do {

```
 str = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("FieldName"));
 ab.add(str);
} while (c1.moveToNext());
```

Comment: ya, i know raw query is more easy but when i read all data out in need to put in in the text for view depend on each textview id , and how ?

Comment: Then Directly use below code 
TextViewId.setText(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("FieldName")));

Comment: cant get your meaning

Comment: TextView t1=(TextView)findViewByid(R.id.textview1);
you have done this in your code for all textviews. 
then just write like
t1.setText(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("FieldName")));